# Javascript Keyboard Event change marked text

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, dom-events

I have an input field which looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="definemonth" value="'.$monthStart.'" class="form-control"
onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this.value);" />
```

To allow only numbers between 1 and 28 (each included) I wrote this piece of JS code:

```
var input = event.key;
var newValue = value + input;

if(input == "ArrowLeft" || input == "ArrowRight" || input == "ArrowUp" ||
   input == "ArrowDown" || input == "Backspace" || input == "Delete" || input == "Enter")
{
    return true;
}

if (!input.match("^[0-9]$") || newValue > 28 || newValue < 1)
{
    return false;
}

return true;
```

It works mostly as I want it to. I want to be able to use the Arrow Keys, the backspace and delete button which works all just fine. But the issue is that I can not mark the text and then add a new number. With marking I mean this kind of marking: [image]
The marking works fine but any key stroke does not change anything at all.

I tried to detect with

```
console.log(input);
```

what happens there but I do not get any output in the console at all.

**My question is** then how do I have to change my code to be able to enter a new value when the text is marked and I type <kbd>1</kbd> for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear selected text before checking new value for allowability.

Like this:

```
var clearValue = element.value;
clearValue = clearValue.slice(0, element.selectionStart) + clearValue.slice(element.selectionEnd);

var newValue = clearValue + input;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1Ljzqmj/1/)

Comment: GReat, this works. But I do not fully understand it. I will accept your answer and if you can explain this I will also upvote it :)